# what are best features

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, preprocessing, ocr

I am doing OCR for Kannada and English. What are the best features in image? Please also tell me some tools to perform OCR before implementing it as code (like Rapiedminer for machine learning).

Comment: This question seems to be poorly researched, and also not written very well. What have you tried? What are you doing, what are your goals? Do you have any sample images? and similar questions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Tesseract](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is an often used OCR tool, but before that you need to pre-processing your image with some basic operations such as binarization, morphological operation, and [illumination equalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292726/how-to-correct-uneven-illumination-in-images-using-matlab), and letter extraction.